# Python: working with unicode characters

Tags: python, unicode, python-2.x

I'm trying to learn how to work with Unicode in python.

Let's say I have a file `test` containing Unicode characters:
`áéíóúabcdefgçë`
I want to make a python script that prints out all the unique characters in the file. This is what I have:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

def main():
    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        print("Argument required.")
        exit()
    else:
        filename = sys.argv[1]
        with open(filename, "r") as fp:
            string = fp.read().replace('\n', '')
        chars = set()
        for char in string:
            chars.add(char)
        for char in chars:
            sys.stdout.write(char)
        print("")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This doesn't print the Unicode characters properly:

```
$ ./unicode.py test
▒a▒bedgf▒▒▒▒c▒▒
```

What is the correct way to do this, so that the characters print properly?

Comment: What version of Python are you using, and what platform are you on? And what encoding is that file `test` stored in?

Comment: If you don't know how to answer the last part, if you're on Python 3, try this: `with open(filename,'rb') as f: print(f.read())` and then show us the `b'…whatever…'` that gets printed out.

Comment: once you have the encoding, if it is non-standard you should open the file as binary (`open(filename, 'rb')`) and then use `.decode([encoding name])` on the read string

Comment: Python 2.7.5, running Scientific Linux 7 (similar to red hat and centos). The encoding is: text/plain; charset=utf-8.

Comment: Also, when I do "print(string)" it prints properly: "áéíóúabcdefgçë". Only when I print char by char do I get the bad output.

Comment: @csunday95 what is the advantage of your proposed method over `open(filename, encoding=[encoding_name])`?

Comment: @lenz Using the open() interface directly would also be appropriate in most cases, but with the binary mode one could inspect a file header that indicates encoding if it's unknown at the time of opening e.g. python source files that indicates the encoding at the top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is encoded, most likely as utf-8.  Utf-8 uses more than one byte to encode non-ascii characters, such as `áéíóú`.  Iterating over a string encoded as utf-8 yields the individual *bytes* that make up the string, rather than the *characters* that you are expecting.

```
>>> s = 'áéíóúabcdefgçë'
# There are 14 characters in s, but it contains 21 bytes
>>> len(s)
21
>>> s
'\xc3\xa1\xc3\xa9\xc3\xad\xc3\xb3\xc3\xbaabcdefg\xc3\xa7\xc3\xab'

# The first "character" (actually, byte) is unprintable.
>>> print s[0]
�
# So is the second.
>>> print s[1]
�
# But together they make up a character.
>>> print s[0:2]
á
```

So printing individual bytes doesn't work as expected.

```
>>> for c in s:print c,
... 
� � � � � � � � � � a b c d e f g � � � �
```

But decoding the string to unicode, then printing does.

```
>>> for c in s.decode('utf-8'):print c,
... 
á é í ó ú a b c d e f g ç ë
```

To make your code work as you expect, you need to decode the string you read from the file.  Change

```
string = fp.read().replace('\n', '')
```

to

```
string = fp.read().replace('\n', '').decode('utf-8')
```

Answer (score -2):

This depends on the version of Python you are using:

**1.** For the python 2, there was no native support for Unicode characters, so it was necessary to leave explicit, with a header such as:

```
# -*-coding:utf-8-*-
```

**2.** For python 3 The support is native, as it says [here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html#python-s-unicode-support).

So the `UTF-8` encoding already has native support.

Comment: The question is about reading Unicode from a file. Your answer is about including Unicode characters in your source code. Two totally different things.

Comment: I'm sorry, i mistook the question and answered it in a misguided way.